# Should full nodes be public?

Tags: security, iri-node

Since part of the security comes from it being hard to find enough nodes to peer with to influence the selected transactions, should full nodes be mostly hidden?

Will a IOTA attack consist of botnets scanning for nodes to peer with?

Should all full nodes be public but not accept peering automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Full nodes should not be public.

Some reasons:

- If they were, attackers could easily find out, which nodes they have to connect to, in order to get the best result out of an attack. ([Omnipresence](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/677/10), [Double Spending](http://www.tangleblog.com/2017/07/10/is-double-spending-possible-with-iota/))
- If they were displayed in an ordered list, people would very likely pick the first few or as their neighbours. This would result in a few nodes with a lot of neighbours and a lot of nodes with very few neighbours.

## How am I supposed to get neighbours?

Ask for neighbours in the [#nodesharing](https://iotatangle.slack.com) channel of the [IOTA-Slack](https://iotatangle.slack.com) and wait for people to send you their IPs.

There are some plans to make it easier and more secure to find neighbours. ([Nelson](https://medium.com/deviota/carriota-nelson-in-a-nutshell-1ee5317d8f19), [Github](https://github.com/SemkoDev/nelson.cli))

Answer (score 3):

Should IOTA grow automatic node discovery is a must. The more nodes the better the network will be. Manual node management could kill the platform. [CarrIOTA Nelson](https://medium.com/deviota/carriota-nelson-in-a-nutshell-1ee5317d8f19) seems be promissing for the discovery task. And Nelson managed nodes are in fact publicly exposed.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered good practice to NOT expose your full node's IP to the public. If I was a hacker wanting to crash the IOTA network I guess I'd appreciate a list of all full node IP's very much. It would provide an incredibly easy DDoS target.
So, join IOTA's slack channel and post a message saying that you setup a full node and then wait for private messages from other full node operators. This, I think, is still the safest way.

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying that full nodes should not be open for everyone?

Comment: So a few nodes get DDosed. That's hardly something any distributed network cares about...

Comment: @w00t: sorry for the confusion: I forgot to negate the first sentence after making some changes. AFAIK you should NOT write your IP publicly visible. If everybody did, a DDoS would be much easier on all those nodes, wouldn't it?